# Is exception is cause of not installing Google Speech Recognition API?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Currently, I am doing speech recognition in python. At first I installed the following…

```
 pip3 install SpeechRecognition
 pip install pipwin
 pipwin install pyaudio
```

And I write the following lines of codes…

```
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Speak Anything')
    audio=r.listen(source)

try:
    text=r.recognize.google(audio)
    print('Your speech :{}',format(text))
except:
    print('Sorry ')
```

But the output is not as expected and as follows…

```
Speak Anything
Sorry could not recognize your voice
```

How to solve it, and how to download google Speech Recognition API?

Comment: Please print the full stack trace and message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has to do with the fact that you are mixing `pip3` and `pip` installations? Only use one for the `python` version that you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need pipwin if you are on Python 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6, because the wheels for [pyaudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files) are available on PyPi.

You can create and activate a virtualenv, for instance:

```
C:\Users\login\virtualenv>"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" -m venv my_reco
C:\Users\login\virtualenv>my_reco\Scripts\activate
```

Then you can install your packages like this:

```
(my_reco) C:\Users\login\virtualenv>pip install SpeechRecognition
[...]
Successfully installed SpeechRecognition-3.8.1

(my_reco) C:\Users\login\virtualenv>pip install pyaudio
[...]
Successfully installed pyaudio-0.2.11
```

Answer (score 0):

No,

You typed the wrong command

it is:

'text=r.recognize_google(audio)'

not:

'text=r.recognize.google(audio)'